# Is this class structurally correct?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I use in final class this switch case:

```
$class = get_class($exception);

    switch ($class) {
        case \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class:
            return self::fail(
                'page not found'
            );
        case \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class:
            return self::fail(
                'entity not found'
            );
        case \Illuminate\Database\QueryException::class:
            return self::fail(
                Str::contains($exception->getMessage(), 'Duplicate') ? 'duplicate error' : 'query error' // Check Query Exception Error
            );
        case \TypeError::class:
            return self::fail(
                'type error'
            );
        case ServiceException::class:
            /** @var ServiceException $exception */
            return self::fail(
                $exception->getMessage(),
                $exception->getErrors()
            );
        default:
            return self::fail(
                $exception->getMessage()
            );
    }
```

when i use phpinsights package for check code, I see this line:

`Having`classes`with more than 5 cyclomatic complexity is prohibited - Consider refactoring:`

how refactor my code?

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor them to separate classes, use the `strategy` pattern. However, I think for such a simple implementation, that is unnecessary.

Perhaps a more suitable approach, is creating a `lookup table` using an array. The key of the array is the class name of the exception, the value is a Closure that you should replace by your "fail" implementation.

I find that [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/smells/switch-statements) provides a lot of valuable information about this.

Example refactor:

```
$exceptionLookupTable = [

   NotFoundHttpException::class => function() { 
       return 'HTTP error stuff'; 
   },
  
   ModelNotFoundException::class => function() { 
       return 'Model error stuff'; 
   },
  
  TypeError::class => function() { 
      return 'Type error stuff'; 
  },
  
  ServiceException::class => function() { 
      return 'Service error stuff'; 
  },

];

$exception = new TypeError; // create example type error

$class = get_class($exception);

$handler = $exceptionLookupTable[$class] ?? function() { 
    return 'do stuff'; // this is the default case
};

$handler(); // returns "Type error stuff"
```

Any new errors can simply be added to the `exception lookup table`.